# microsoft speech api bad request

Tags: web-services, speech-to-text, bad-request, web-api-testing

can anyone check if there are error/s on my code: this is to pass byte for the microsoft speech api, however i received 400 bad request error. wav file format is correct since i used the sample from microsoft. any help would be appreciated!

```
public void speechToText(){
    String Key = "mysubscriptionkey";
    try {
        File file = new File("filepath", "filename.wav");
        URL url = new URL("https://westus.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?langauge=en-US&format=simple");

        HttpURLConnection con =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.addRequestProperty("Content-type", "audio/wav; codec=\"audio/pcm\"; samplerate=16000"); 
        con.addRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", Key);

        byte[] bytes = ReadFully(file);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(bytes);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getInputStream()); 
        String responseBody = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        System.out.println(responseBody);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

--this one to read audio

```
public byte[] ReadFully(File file){
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try{
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        OutputStream outputstream ;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return out.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have the logs for this ? or a cURL command ?

Comment: Also, The content type looks a bit incorrect to me ! Can you try with the below ?

con.addRequestProperty("Content-type", "audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000");